# TypeError: Cannot Read property prototype of undefined thrown from require('express') statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I am working on a project in WebStorm, using [grant-express](https://github.com/simov/grant) to handle OAuth.  When I compile code containing the following statement (or other statements using require()), copied from the grant-express readme, I get compiler warnings and a runtime error.

```
var express = require('express');
```

Warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
Runtime error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I know this is a little vague, but does anyone know why I'm getting these warnings/errors and/or how to solve them?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `package.json`?